# Create customer group with Magento API SOAP 2

Tags: c#, magento

Is there any way to create a **customer group** with magento api soap 2?

I'm trying to c # but can not find how to do it.

Regards

Comment: Read their documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.html

Comment: Thanks, I have previously read the documentation but what I want is to create a customer group http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer_group.html

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Sorry.